# Intellisense for Python keywords in Robot Framework not working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, robotframework

I did my best to overcome this problem but it was in vain. I am developing tests in Robot Framework (RF) in Visual Studio Code and I want it to either show "signatures" of keywords from standard libraries or to be able to go to their definitions. *Go to definition* and signature displaying when hovering with Ctrl key are behaving this way:

- works for my keywords written in RF (hoorah!)
- works for my keywords written in Python only if a keyword consists of one word (I think conversion between undescores and spaces is failing)
- does not work for keywords from standard libraries even if the keyword is one-word (e.g. "Fail"), regardless whether the keyword comes from built-in libraries or other ones (e.g. SeleniumLibrary)

When failing, *Robot Framework Intellisense Server* gives me message "Keyword definition 'Blah Blah' not found from the workspace".

I am using plugins *Robot Framework Intellisense FORK* and/or *Robot Framework Language Server*. I tried to configure them carefully according their documentation (*Details*), but the best state I reached is described above.

Can you help me please? I do not need to use a specific plugin, I just need to have the signature or documentation (or implementation) of every keyword in my code to be one click far.

Answer (score 0):

According to [their documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Snooz82.rf-intellisense) they support

```
Goto definition
   For variables
   For user keywords
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to partially solve this when I not only open the folder with source code, but create a workspace and add the folder containing standard libraries to it as well (*Add Folder to Workspace*). I do not know exactly which folder is the best to add, it seems `...\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\` to me.